# По направлению, в направлении, по направлению к — какой предлог выбрать?

Tags: синтаксис, предлоги, падежи

Речь идет об адресате, в направлении (по направлению?) которого движется посылка. Какой предлог следует употребить и какой падеж выбрать?

Comment: По-моему, так говорят о реальном движении в пространстве, а не о доставке  посылок.

Comment: @М_Г, что-то это мне напоминает. ) Не знаю, какое здесь движение (реальное или мнимое), но точно знаю, что посылка передвигается по сортировочным пунктам в сторону адресата.

Comment: Как-то странно говорить об этом. А куда ей еще двигаться?

Comment: @М_Г, а куда ей работник почты напишет, туда и будет двигаться. В любом случае вопрос не о движении, а о предлоге.

Comment: А как Вы себе представляете "по направлению" без "к"? Приведите пример.

Comment: @М_Г, "Не важно, в какой части России ты живешь, но посылка всегда пойдет на сортировку сначала в Москву, а потом уже по направлению адресата" — именно так я написал на одном форуме, это часть моего вопроса. Потом уже заподозрил что-то неладное.

Comment: Кажется, это то же, что и по окончании/по окончанию. В первом случае предлог, во втором - существительное с предлогом. Вижу, что, скорее всего, ошибка, однако в Нацкорпусе достаточно примеров без "к", в которых речь именно о значении в сторону чего-либо, в направлении.

Comment: "А сам-то он где? Корнилов махнул рукой по направлению дороги. ― В своём кооперативе". Вот, скажем. Как тут понимать? Махнул рукой в направлении дороги (то есть показал, где дорога) или махнул в ту же сторону, в которую ведет дорога (то есть по направлению)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**«По направлению к Свану»**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E_%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83) (фр. *Du côté de chez Swann*) — первая книга Марселя Пруста из цикла «В поисках утраченного времени».

[Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)

> **НАПРАВЛЕНИЕ** — **1. в направлении** чего / (устар.) к чему. *Цербер,
> издав громкий торопливый лай в направлении конского топота, последовал
> за мною* (Кор.); *...Они обыкновенно под вечер исчезали именно в
> направлении к часовне* (Кор.). **2. по направлению к** чему / (устар.)
> чего. *Свернули в сторону по направлению к заброшенным кирпичным
> сараям* (Чир.); *Ольга слушала голоса весенней ночи и смотрела по
> направлению города* (Чир.). См. **в — по**.

Смотрим там, куда нас послали (всю тему):

**В — ПО** (предлоги).

> При указании пространства или времени предлоги синонимичны, но в
> сочетании с некоторыми существительными различаются оттенками
> значения.
>
> **1.** При указании пространства: *ездить в города* (указание на направление действия) — *ездить по городам* (указание на
> последовательное распространение действия на ряд объектов); *гулять в
> лесу* (указывается только место совершения действия) — *гулять по
> лесу* (содержится дополнительный оттенок распространения действия по
> всему пространству); *ударить в лоб* (указание на ограниченное место,
> например: *ударили в лоб камнем*) — *ударить по лбу* (указание на
> распространение действия по поверхности, например: *ударить линейкой
> по лбу*).
>
> **2.** При указании времени: *навещать в праздники* (указание на совершение действия в определенные дни) — *навещать по праздникам*
> (указание на регулярное повторение действия).
>
> **3.** Конструкции равноценны: *в меру / по мере сил; в направлении / по направлению к чему; в сравнении / по сравнению* с чем. Например:
> *Оказывали помощь по мере сил; Помогали чем могли, по мере сил; Пошёл по жёлтому и сырому песку в направлении ключа* (Т.); *...Пошёл прочь,
> по направлению к городу* (М. Г.); *Он осознавал, что такое чувство
> было бы оскорбительно даже в отношении собаки* (Ч.); *Он готов был
> явиться резким и даже беспощадным по отношению к человеку* (Фед.); *Он
> всегда чувствовал несправедливость своего избытка в сравнении с
> бедностью народа* (Л. Т.); *Мои неприятности — это капля по сравнению
> с морем твоих* (Сим.).

На бис: *конструкции равноценны: **в направлении / по направлению к чему.***

Comment: Да, надо бы взять на заметку, что есть такие _словари управления_, кто ж знал? Точно не я...

Answer (score 1):

Отправитель лишь указывает адрес получателя, а почтовые направления отлажены без него. Посылка движется в направлении адресата(род. падеж). По направлению мы идём на укол, - нас врач направил. По направлению навигатора можем ехать, хотя говорим: "еду по навигатору ", - опуская слово "направление", но подразумевая его, так как навигатор направляет нас (через 300 метров поверните налево, через 200 метров крутой поворот направо и т. д.).  В вашем случае фраза - "по направлению адресата" выглядит так,  словно её направил сам адресат.